# Is there a OS/user-wide log to log to?

Tags: logs, curl

I'm using [curl to dowload a jar from a TESTDRIVE script](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2011-04/0075.html) and for debugging purposes it helps to log the http headers returned to a log file. But logging them in the working dir (where the script is executed from) is inconvenient (for the user). I was wondering if there was a /logs/log in unix systems where applications could log their stuff.

Console in the mac indeed seems to pickup logs from multiple applications, somehow.

Answer (score 6):

There's a system log facility: [syslog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog). From a shell script, call the [`logger`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/logger.1.html) command.

```
logger -p 'user.info' "hello world"
```

However, this is for *system* logs, not for logs intended for a particular user. If the logs are intended for the user who's running the application, then a log file is more appropriate (something like `~/.application-name/downloads.log`). An alternate approach would be to send a local mail, but that's only for cases where the user must see the logs, not if they're intended for debugging.

Even if system logs are the right place, a full transcript of HTTP headers is too much information. Log one line in the system logs, and put the transcript in a file in an application-specific directory under `/var`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use syslog:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog